# Java hexadecimal

Tags: java, hex

I have a message

```
static int[] message = {
        0x01, 0x10, 0x00,
        0x01, // port addres 01 - 08
        0x00, 0x01, 0x02,
        0x06, 0x00,
        0xA4, 0x21
};
```

I know the data are right, as of I'm writing them to COM port with RXTX, and I got right HW reaction

I know that `0x01` is `1` value, and sent really like `01` (which is two bits, quarter byte long)

When I need to adjust the message, is generating values like this right?

```
message[index] = 1 & 0xff
```

I see the output of this snippet, and it looks properly

```
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    System.out.println(i & 0xff);
}
```

Is there any sheet you'd recommend me to read?
Is storing these numbers in `int` right, as we cannot use `byte (-128, +127)` for values up to `<0x00, 0xFF>` range

Comment: You can use bytes. But you have to cast every value to byte: `byte[] message = {(byte) 0xff};`

Comment: *"I know that OxO1 is 1 value, and sent really like 01 (which is two bits)"* Not unless you're doing something to make that happen. A Java `int` is a 32-bit value ([reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)). Just because the value doesn't *require* all of those bits doesn't mean they aren't sent. The size of what you're sending could be limited by how you're sending it, but given the other values you quote, you can be sure you're sending at least eight of the bits.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using ByteBuffer

Comment: And also, what do you mean by "adjust the message"?

Comment: @fge adjust message, means change the values within message frame

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for notice, but looks like, it work's properly with int[] and byte[] (using `OutputStream` `write(int)` and `write(byte[])`). How can I find out what is really sent?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux thanks, it works, I was afraid of using casting

Comment: @MarekSebera: If you're using `OutputStream#write`, what gets sent will depend entirely on the concrete implementation. `OutputStream` is an abstract class defining semantics for writing to streams; it doesn't define the stream itself. A concrete subclass is required to actually define what gets written. A `FileOutputStream` and a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and a `PipedOutputStream` all output the data differently.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you please consider creating an answer from your comments? I think here it kinda drowns

Comment: @MarekSebera: As you've now accepted an answer, presumably you feel the question is answered and I'll leave it. I commented rather than answering because I didn't feel it *answered* the question, just commented on an aspect of it. Good luck with things!

Comment: @MarekSebera: The final arbiter of whether a question was answered is whether the person *asking* the question thinks it was. :-) So I've converted the comments into an answer. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use a `ByteBuffer` for what you need, and wrap it under a class.

I don't know your exact message format, but let's say for a moment this is 3 bytes of data and 1 byte of a port:

```
public final class Message
{
    private static final MESSAGE_SIZE = 4;
    private static final PORT_OFFSET=3;

    private final ByteBuffer buf;

    public Message()
    {
        buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(MESSAGE_SIZE);
    }

    public void setPort(final byte b)
    {
        buf.put(PORT_OFFSET, b);
    }

    // etc

    public byte[] getRaw()
    {
        return buf.array();
    }
}
```

You can even use ByteBuffer's hashCode() and equals() to compare messages, *if you only ever use absolute get/put methods* (otherwise quite a bit of gymnastic is in order).

I used this technique to read/write NRPE packets.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that 0x01 is 1 value, and sent really like 01 (which is two bits)

That's only true if you're doing something to make that happen. A Java `int` is a 32-bit value ([reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)). Just because the value doesn't require all of those bits doesn't mean they aren't sent, because you *may* need all of the bits for a different value. The size of what you're sending could be limited by how you're sending it, but given the other values you quote, you can be sure you're sending at least eight of the bits.

If you're using `OutputStream#write`, what gets sent will depend entirely on the concrete implementation. `OutputStream` is an abstract class defining semantics for writing to streams; it doesn't define the stream itself. A concrete subclass is required to actually define what gets written. A `FileOutputStream` and a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and a `PipedOutputStream` all output the data differently.